# Evaluating values in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fire an event every 30 minutes.
My approach was to check the time using an if statement. I don't want it to fire every second of that minute, so I'm checking the second as well.
From the code below, I would have assumed that if Hour is either 00 or 30 and the Seconds were 00 01 02 it would evaluate as true and move into the if block.
However this is firing every minute when the Seconds element is 00 01 02.

What am I missing!?

```
if (time.strftime("%M")) == ("00") or (time.strftime("%M")) == ("30") and (time.strftime("%S")) == ("00") or (time.strftime("%S")) == ("01") or (time.strftime("%S")) == ("02"):
```

Comment: Don't use `time.strftime()` for this. Use `time.minute` and `time.second`. Then you can use modulus: `if time.minute in (0, 30) and time.second in (0, 1, 2):`

Comment: I'd suggest using some sort of regex to verify the time. Might be easier depending on your cases.

Comment: There's also a `cron` library for Python that runs code on a schedule. This may be better than a loop that keeps checking the time.

Comment: I think the issue might be that your combination of `or` and `and` conditions are not working the way you think they should. Maybe add parentheses?

Comment: Why don't use `time.sleep(30*60)` in a loop ? No date comparison. Just fire your event and sleep for 30 minutes and loop.
It works if you don't care being synchronized on the exact half-hour.

Comment: Or use a library like https://github.com/Miksus/rocketry